# Can't show data with postgres + php

Tags: php, html, postgresql

i'm trying to make a web app with php and postgres but i have problems showing the data.

This is my view, it's just a simple login.

```
<form method="post" action="../Controlador/logueo.php" role="form" class="form-inline">

      <div class="form-group">

        <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu usuario">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">

        <br>
        <input name="contraseña" type="password" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Contraseña">
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

This is ../Controlador/logueo.php and here is where i have problems. I can't show the info in $alumno (the variable in foreach), i tried to make an echo and nothing happens...

```
<?php
include("../Modelo/alumno.php");
$al = new alumno();
$alumnos = $al->obtenerAlumnos();
echo $alumnos;
foreach ($alumnos as $alumno) {
    echo $alumno[0];
    if ($alumno[0] == $_POST[nombre]  && $alumno[5] == $_POST[contraseña] ){
        //Do something
    }
}
?>
```

And this is Modelo/alumno.php

```
<?php

class alumno
{

    function _construct()
    {

    } 

    function obtenerAlumnos()
    {
         include("conexion.php");
         $query = "SELECT * FROM alumno";
         $result  = pg_query($squery);
         $alumnos =  array();
         while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
         array_push($alumnos, $row);
    }
    return $alumnos;
    }

}

?>
```

finally i have Conexion.php

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Tarea3BD user=postgres password=motorola13")
  or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
?>
```

Hope someone can help me, i'm new with php and postgres.
Many thanks.

Comment: You have a typo: `$result  = pg_query($squery);` `$squery` instead of `$query`

Comment: whats the error you are getting. Change as mentioned in above comment

Comment: Aw, if only I had a Gold Badge in the [php] tag, this question could have been asked, solved, and closed ("Off-topic: ... due to a simply typographical error ... unlikely to help future users.") within 5 minutes.

Comment: Upvoted anyway, because you actually included enough code to allow a useful and immediate answer.